# How can I preserve changes to a auto generated file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf

I would like to save (or automatically make) changes to the References.cs file that is generated from a service reference whenever it is regenerated.

```
[field:NonSerialized] // code to add after updating service reference
public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Comment: And _why_ would you want to do that (the change itself, not the persisting)?

Comment: Because I'm saving the information I get from the service to a file, and that handler isn't serializable.

Comment: Is only serializing the properties an option?

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of different types of information coming from the server and any other means of saving the data would be too much of a hassle. I was hoping there would be some way to tell VS to add the line(s) to the file, even though it is just a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can add attributes to via buddy classes?  This way you don't have to touch the generated classes

- [How to: Add Metadata Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee707339%28v=vs.91%29.aspx)
- [using metadata classes outside dynamic data](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2009/07/24/using-an-associated-metadata-class-outside-dynamic-data.aspx)

[Edit 1] I realized that this technique is not going to work for events :(

[Edit 2]  How about creating a partial class and removing the handlers while serializing the code

```
public partial class MyClass // partial to the generated class
{
    [OnSerializing]
    public void OnSerializingMethod(StreamingContext context)
    {
        foreach(var d  in MyEvent.GetInvocationList())
        {
            MyEvent -= (PropertyChangedEventHandler) d;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm finding difficulty in adding an attribute to something other than a property :/

Comment: You are right, after your comment I noticed that you are trying to use this for events

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply, I kept myself busy with other parts of the program. I tried your solution, but it didn't seem to work and since I didn't have time to investigate further, I went instead for a pre-build script : AddNonSerializedAttribute "$(ProjectDir)...Reference.cs" . Thanks anyway, I'm sure buddy classes will come in handy sometime :D